# ¿Cómo recorrer los valores de una matriz e imprimir en otro color un valor de esa matriz?

Tags: python

Tengo que resolver el siguientes problemas de programación en Python:

Genere una matriz de 8x9 que represente una sala de cine.

• Cada silla de la sala debe estar representada por un número consecutivo y
una letra.

• Aleatoriamente reserve 25 espacios, los cuales deben salir de color rojo. De
igual manera, si algunos usuarios han comprado boletos, éstos deben estar
en color rojo también; para visualizarlo, imprima la matriz.

• Mientras que el sistema se esté ejecutando, la matriz que se generó debe
permanecer activa; es decir, en caso de que algún usuario ingrese a la opción
1 del menú, no se debe generar otra matriz con otros espacios reservados,
sino que continúa siendo la misma.

Se debe ver así pero no logro como hacerlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Publica el código (texto, no imagen) que has escrito hasta el momento.

Comment: Este es un programa con una buena lógica y cantidad de líneas de código, por lo que acá no te van a resolver el problema entero. Podría recomendarte el uso de clases (y objetos) para reducir la complejidad de estar interactuando con el objeto "sala de cine".

Comment: ¿A qué menú se refiere ese encunciado? ¿Por dónde se emite esa salida? ¿Es un servidor Web y debes retornar HTML?¿ Es una terminal de texto? Si es lo segundo ¿te han dado el código de cómo cambiar a rojo el texto o debes averiguarlo tú? Qué llevas hecho hasta ahora? Qué parte es la que no sabes hacer?

Comment: Es una terminal de texto y no me han dado el código para cambiar el color de texto y lo que llevo hasta ahorita es                                        espaciosCine = []
def matriz():
    numero = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    letra = "ABCDEFGHI"
    for f in range(len(numero)):
        espaciosCine.append([])
        for c in range(len(letra)):
            espaciosCine[f].append(str(numero[f]) + letra[c])                                Ahora debo encontrar la forma de que se elijan 25 valores al azar, esos pintarlos en rojo y que se imprima igual como en la imagen en la terminal

Comment: Debo hacerlo con el lenguaje Python